# sshd: Problem disabling password authentication from outside LAN

Tags: sshd

I have a CentOS 7 server with 2 NICs, one inside the LAN with a private IP 192.168.1.1 (lan0) and one with a public internet IP (ppp0)

For connections originating from inside the LAN I want password or public key authentication to be available.

For connections originating from the internet, I want public key only. I've done this like so in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
PasswordAuthentication No
```

And then the last lines are:

```
Match address 192.168.1.0/24
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

So to test, I log on to another machine I have which, is VPS on the internet and try to ssh in. As expected I get this:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

But what I'm not understanding is why my /var/log/secure is filled with brute force attempts like this: (IP's changed)

```
Apr 22 09:57:36 linuxhost1 sshd[15149]: input_userauth_request: invalid user webmaster [preauth]
Apr 22 09:57:36 linuxhost1 sshd[15149]: Received disconnect from a.b.c.d: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Apr 22 09:57:36 linuxhost1 sshd[15151]: Invalid user webmaster from a.b.c.d
Apr 22 09:57:36 linuxhost1 sshd[15151]: input_userauth_request: invalid user webmaster [preauth]
Apr 22 09:57:36 linuxhost1 sshd[15151]: Received disconnect from a.b.c.d: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Apr 22 09:57:36 linuxhost1 sshd[15153]: Invalid user webpop from a.b.c.d
Apr 22 09:57:36 linuxhost1 sshd[15153]: input_userauth_request: invalid user webpop [preauth]
Apr 22 09:57:36 linuxhost1 sshd[15153]: Received disconnect from a.b.c.d: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Apr 22 09:57:36 linuxhost1 sshd[15155]: Invalid user web from a.b.c.d
Apr 22 09:57:36 linuxhost1 sshd[15155]: input_userauth_request: invalid user web [preauth]
Apr 22 09:57:36 linuxhost1 sshd[15155]: Received disconnect from a.b.c.d: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Apr 22 09:57:37 linuxhost1 sshd[15157]: Invalid user william from a.b.c.d
Apr 22 09:57:37 linuxhost1 sshd[15157]: input_userauth_request: invalid user william [preauth]
Apr 22 09:57:37 linuxhost1 sshd[15157]: Received disconnect from a.b.c.d: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Apr 22 09:57:37 linuxhost1 sshd[15159]: Invalid user windowserver from a.b.c.d
Apr 22 09:57:37 linuxhost1 sshd[15159]: input_userauth_request: invalid user windowserver [preauth]
Apr 22 09:57:37 linuxhost1 sshd[15159]: Received disconnect from a.b.c.d: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
```

How were these brute force attackers allowed to even input a `username`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [options override for openssh client configuration](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274170/options-override-for-openssh-client-configuration)

Comment: What is your ssh protocol ?

Comment: @Jakuje not a duplicate

Answer (score 2):

> How were these brute force attackers allowed to even input a `username`?

You write username on command-line (or the current is used by default). You always need to input username. You didn't block connection by this (there is `firewalld` or `iptables` for that), but only password authentication.

For people more eager in details, there is [RFC4252, section 5](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4252.txt), which describes `SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST` message, which follows the key exchange. It has a fields with requested username. Either by requesting `password` authentication, which will be rejected, using `pubkey` authentication (will get rejected too, unless your key gets stolen) or `none` (section 5.2), which is basically request to list available methods (and should be the first one tried).

Comment: Ok I will give that a try, but it does seem to work from another host as I mentioned in my OP:
Verbose mode gives

`debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey`

and

`Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: Ok. So it might work.

Comment: basically correct, but (1) username not needed on _command line_ per se; (2) The default `Match *` is not necessary with `sshd_config`; non matching entries will use global configuration, (3) the relevant manual page is `sshd_config` (I have edited your answer)

Comment: @Otheus Yes, the relevant yes, but the quote is from the originally referenced. Never mind ... it is described also in the other ...

Comment: But Jakuje, these are two different configuration files. The quote from the sshd file is this: ` If all of the criteria on the Match line are satisfied, the keywords on the following lines override those set in the global section of the config file, until either another Match line or the end of the file.` That is, the global configuration will be used for no Match, and `match *` is unneeded.

Comment: @Otheus Yes, you are right. Removing the note, since it is irrelevant in this configuration.

Comment: My own observations don't agree with this.

If I repeatedly type `ssh root@linuxhost1` from another host, I see the following lines in `/var/log/secure` on the ssh server:



`Apr 22 16:43:16 linuxhost1 sshd[28023]: Connection closed by x.x.x.x [preauth]`



What I think this is telling me is that the connection was closed before the ssh sever even looked at the username. So why are usernames appearing in the log I posted earlier?

Comment: If you really want to know that, check the RFCs defining the SSH protocol. Mainly [RFC4252, section 5](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4252.txt), which the `SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST` message, which is the first one after key exchange. It provides the `username`.

Answer (score 1):

The public key authentication is *per user*. You need an username, and your key. In fact, you can actually log in to two different users on the same server using the same key.

If you're trying to `ssh invaliduser@your.server.hostname` (with or without a valid key), you'll also get "Permission denied", plus the error shows up in the server's log.

So, this behaviour is intentional and actually doesn't have to do anything with the public key authentication itself.