# Does the default per user .ssh/config file override all options in system wide ssh_config?

Tags: ssh, ssh-config

If there is no `-F` switch and there is an `/home/me/.ssh/config` file that I can expect the settings in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` to be ignored or do the settings in my home directory just supplement the global configuration the way they would if I specified them with a `-o` stanza?

For reference, The `ssh` man page says that the `-F` switch does the following.

> Specifies an alternative per-user configuration file.  If a configuration file is given on the command line, the system-wide configuration file (`/etc/ssh/ssh_config`) will be ignored.  The default for the per-user configuration file is `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: @Jak still not sure if the -F switch is always a complete override,  because the man page makes it seem (to me at least) as if there is an implicit -F ~/.ssh/config if none is specified.   I'm guessing that's not the case though.

Comment: Added explanation for the `-F` switch. It was not clear what exactly you want to know.

Comment: This really doesn't seem to be a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274170/options-override-for-openssh-client-configuration. This question asks about file overriding while the other questions asks about value overriding.

Comment: Since this is marked a duplicate (incorrectly IMHO) I can't give full answer below, so short answer is: You can **not** expect `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` to be ignored. The man page (https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) states that "ssh(1) obtains configuration data from the following sources in the following order: command-line, ~/.ssh/config, /etc/ssh/ssh_config". You can, however, expect your settings to override ssh_config on a parameter by parameter basis. Also from the man page - "For each parameter, the first obtained value will be used.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can expect the settings in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` to be ignored?

Yes. `ssh` reads `-F` command-line option, which will [set the `config` variable](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/04c091fc199f17dacf8921df0a06634b454e2722/ssh.c#L982):

```
case 'F':
    config = optarg;
    break;
```

and later on calls [the `process_config_files` function](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/04c091fc199f17dacf8921df0a06634b454e2722/ssh.c#L530), which either:

- reads config specified on command-line, or
- reads the other two (`/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and `~/.ssh/config`) files.

Additionally specifying `none` on command-line (`-F none`) will cause that no configuration file is loaded. See linked function source code for more details how this switch is handled.